# Overwatch Update Keeps Restarting After Finishing

Tags: overwatch

Since updating to patch 1.4.0.2 (1.68GB), Overwatch keeps restarting the update, like this:

1. Overwatch starts updating to the new patch
2. Update finishes
3. Update starts all over again

Is it a problem with my PC, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I happened to have the same issue. Not to worry, you can try selecting the options button once your in the battle.net desktop app on the Overwatch section and continue to select the option for 'scan and repair' and allow it to scan for a while. After, it will download the necessary remaining files needed to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

After updating, try closing everything related to overwatch in taskmanager (use ctrl + shift + esc) , and after that, restart your computer, and open overwatch again.

If this doent fix the problem, Try reinstalling the game, and apply update after

Comment: It didn't help ,the update resumes after restarting my PC either way thanks. ill just continue the update and maybe send a ticket to blizzard